# HTML5/JS APP Data Storage (IndexedDB or SQLLite)

Tags: html, sqlite, windows-store-apps, indexeddb

I am developing a forms app for windows store platform using HTML5/JS. APP needs to store data locally (images, json, generated Pdfs etc) . App would mostly work in offline mode, but on obtaining internet connectivity data will be synced with the web server app.

My question is, **Is SQLLite an option for me considering this is a HTML5 application on Windows store**. I tried searching on MSDN to see the recommended  way of using SQLLite in a HTML5/JS windows store app but couldn't find anything.

Second alternative is IndexedDB. Is that a good choice considering the amount of data that is required to be stored here locally

Comment: IndexedDB is an API for storing data in browser database, a similar API is (actually was) WebSQL. WebSQL enables to store data in an SQLLite database. I guess in 2010 WebSQL API is deprecated by W3C, so now if you want to store anything in browser database then only option you have IndexedDB. If you want to store file PDFs, images etc. then you have to look for some File API .. Hope this helps ..

Answer (score 0):

The default amount of data in an indexeddb store is 250mb for Apps if I'm correct.

One thing you need to keep in mind is that indexeddb is a NOSQL database so it will be a different approach than using SQLLite. I don't know the details for using SQLLite on a windows store app, but the advantage of the indexeddb is that it's build-in HTML5, so if you ever wanted to port this to a webapp it can be done more easily.